# JCrop - FancyBox -- Jcrop is not working properly

Tags: jquery, fancybox, jcrop

Jcrop is working good without fancybox.
But if i load Jcrop inside Fancybox, I am not able to crop the images.

Images are displayed two times in the browser.
I guess it should be a css problem or something.

Is there any solution?

Comment: I found that fancybox and jcrop works properly. I use image upload in fancybox, in the next stop, i load the uploaded image in fancybox to crop. I found jcrop is not working there...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***Update:** In Fancybox 2 the "onComplete" function has been renamed to "afterShow". Change code accordingly if you've upgraded :)*

Try setting the image source and running Jcrop on the "oncomplete"-callback of fancybox and it should work just fine:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
  var imagetoload = '/path/to/yourimage.jpg' /* Set to your image here */
  $('.fancyboxitem').fancybox(
  {
    'content':'<div><img id="jcropImage" /></div>', 
    'onComplete':function() 
      {
        $('#jcropImage')
          .attr('src', imagetoload)
          .Jcrop(
            { 
            /* Jcrop settings here */
            },
            function() { $.fancybox.resize(); /*Jcrop onload callback */ }); 
      }
  });
});
</script>

<a href="#" class="fancyboxitem">Open fancybox</a>
```

If you don't set a width and height of the Jcrop object and fancybox you need to run $.fancybox.resize() as a callback after you've loaded the Jcrop object. Since you're loading the images dynamically the fancybox will open with a width and height of 0 otherwise.

Good luck!

Comment: THANK YOU for this.  You don't know how much time yesterday I spent trying to figure out how to keep Fancybox and JCrop from doing battle.  +10.

Comment: I don't remember how long I battled with this before finding the solution myself but it took a while. Happy to be of assistance!

Comment: I am using fancybox 3 and there is no resize method :/

Answer (score 1):

Slightly adapted version:

```
$.fancybox({
    href : '/path-to-image.jpg',
    afterShow : function(){
        $( '.fancybox-inner' ).find( 'img' ).Jcrop({                    

        });
    }
});
```